# VBA Find Value and then go left till specifi value

Tags: vba, excel

Hello in my Code i want to find a specific Value and then the code should go to the left, till he finds another Value.

In the Picture you can see my table:
[image]

So if i add a new row to the "working plan" then i want that the code goes from the last cell with value one to the left and find the first "MFG" in "storage" after that the code should go to the left till he finds "MFG5". After that he copies the color and add it to "AGA" (This part is already solved).

Here is my Code so far.

```
Sub Color_Row()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range

    ' Find MFG in Storage
    fColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 4
    rowIdx = Columns(fColumn).Find(What:="MFG", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row

    ' Now in Storage go to left an find "MFG5"

    ' Copy Color and Add to "AGA"
    ColorToCopy = Cells(rowIdx, fColumn).Interior.Color
    farbe = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, rng2.Column).Find(What:="DEL", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column - 3
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, farbe).Interior.Color = ColorToCopy
End sub
```

I hope someone can help me with that.

Comment: When you say 'left', do you mean 'right'? Since MFG5 is to the right of MFG, the statement *'go to the left till he finds "MFG5"'* would make more sense.

Comment: Have you already tried to do it manually and record it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use a do while loop?
When i get it right, you have already the cell in which the value 'MFG' is correct?
And then you want to go to the left until the value is 'MFG5', also correct?

```
Dim count As Integer
count = 0 
Do while Worksheets(sheet).Cells(rowIdx, fColumn-count).Value <> "MFG5"
count = count +1
Loop
```

The cell with the value "MFG5" is then Cells(rowIdx, fColumn-count)

Comment: you got all right. Thank you very much, this works fine. Thanks a lot